# Rails Cart deleting itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cart

I'm having an issue with my cart in an e-commerce app.
When the user signs in and adds an item to Cart, the item does not add immediately.
The user has to go back and add it a second time before it goes into the cart.

I've looked at the logs and i've been able to find that the issue occurs when a user has previously purchased something and is signing to purchase at a later time.The next time they log in to purchase another item, is when it occurs.

The system tries to delete the old cart and create a new one but what ultimately happens is, the new cart shows up empty on first attempt.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
class Customer::CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
      if current_user
    if current_user.cart.purchased_at
        session[:cart_id] = nil
    else
    @cart = current_user.cart ||= Cart.find_by(session[:cart_id])
    end 
end
if session[:cart_id].nil?
    current_user.cart = Cart.create!(user_id: params[:id])
    session[:cart_id] = current_user.cart.id 
end
@cart = current_user.cart
end
```

The Cart Controller create action

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.save
    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Cart Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

def add_product(product_id, size)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id, size: size)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, size: size)
    end
    return current_item
end

def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end

end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable,
has_one :cart
after_create :default_cart

def add_products_from_session cart_id
if role == customer?
  session_cart = Cart.find cart_id if cart_id
end
if cart && session_cart
  session_cart.line_items.each{ |li| self.cart.line_items << li }
  session_cart.reload
  session_cart.destroy
elsif session_cart
  self.cart = session_cart
end

private
  def default_cart
   self.create_cart
  end
end
```

Code that adds product to Cart

From the Line Item Controller

```
  def create
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, params[:size])

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to customer_cart_path }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Could you also add your Cart and User models please?

Comment: @GrahamS. added

Comment: What is the controller#action that produces unexpected behavior? Have you written a test for it by any chance?

Comment: @eeeeeean The Show action above! No, i've not written a test

Answer (score 0):

`Cart.create!(user_id: params[:id])` looks strange. I think it should be `Cart.create!(user_id: current_user.id)` or  `current_user.create_cart`.  Furthor more you have to change a little your code. I suggest:

```
def show
  setup_cart
end



def create
  setup_cart
  # ... your code
end

protected

def setup_cart
  # user logged in
  if current_user
    # when cart purchased reset existing one
    if current_user.cart.purchased_at
       session[:cart_id] = nil
       current_user.cart = nil       
    end 

    # use existing one, marked in session or create a new one 
    @cart = current_user.cart || Cart.where(id: session[:cart_id]).first || current_user.create_cart
    @cart.user = current_user # in case first login
    @cart.save!
  else # no user logged in
    @cart = Cart.where(id: session[:cart_id]).first || Cart.create! 
  end

  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Maybe another action alters `session[:cart_id]` or  `current_user.cart `

Comment: No error but the item just doesn't go into the cart the first time. Maybe i didn't explain properly. This action gets triggered when you click 'add to cart', so its trying to clear the cart and add an item simultaneously and basically, you end up with an empty cart on first attempt.

Comment: So you have to inspect the action where you call `add_product` or `add_products_from_session`. The `show` action should not be the issue any more. Please add the code for your action where you add the product to the cart.

Comment: Your code does not show how `@cart` is set for action `create`. You can extract the code from `show` and use a `before_action` or call the extracted method from `show` and `create`. I will change my example accordingly.

Comment: I've added the main Cart controller now